# Univalent functions normal family.

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove that:

The family of $S$ of univalent functions on the unit disc with f(0)=0, f'(0)=1 is a normal family.

I'm pretty sure i have to do it with **Zalcmans Lemma**:

a family of analytic functions on the unit disc with f(0)=0 are not normal if and only if there exists:
(1) a sequence $(z_n)$ converging to $z_\infty$
(2)a sequence of positive reals $(p_n)$ convering to zero
(3) a sequence of functions in the family such that $f_n(z_n+p_nx)-f_n(z_n)$ converge on compact subsets to the entire identity function.

I know there are more complicated ways to treat the problem, but it is not supposed to be solved with advanced theory like the growth theorem/distortion theorem.

Please be so kind not to post a solution right away, but instead hint me how to solve the problem. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show that a family of univalent functions, $f_n(0)=0$, $f_n'(0)=1$ is a normal family.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1612219/show-that-a-family-of-univalent-functions-f-n0-0-f-n0-1-is-a-normal-f)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try applying Montel's theorem to the related family of functions $\sqrt{f'(z)}$.  Notice that the square roots may be chosen so that they all omit $-1$.

Comment: Thank you for your hint. I just read that the author do not wish solutions posted on the internet, so i ask future readers to use this hint, but not post the full solution as an answer.

Comment: How can you have that $\sqrt{f'}$ omits $-1$?